# Open popup window in specific keyboard language

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I have code like this that open new window in javascript:

```
window.open(URL);
```

But although browser keyboard language at opennig moment for example is 'fa' but new window opens in 'en'.

Is there a way that I can open new window in the same keyboard language that browser uses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It seems that only my system behaved in this way.

When I tested that code on some other's computer, it worked well. It seems I just had bad keyboard settings.

To resolve the problem I just changed my switching policy from 'Window' to 'Application' in keyboard settings (Kubuntu) and everythings worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in you taskbar a preferred language button?

Try to find out how to enable this under your OS, because normally you can change it with this language switch button by focusing on the wanted window then switching to the wanted language.

Comment: Yes, I have that button. It have two values 'fa' and 'en'. I set it to 'fa' but popup window opens in 'en'. But when I open new window for example in Chrome it automatically opens in 'fa'!

Comment: try to open the popup, change the setting for this popup, then closing the popup by holding CTRL. Retry opening it and check the language.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's depends only on browser and OS settings. Javascript just tell to open new window (BTW in common case it will be popup, not tab).

If you using Ubuntu as OS u can check Text entry in keyboard settings. There you can find allowing different sources for separated languages.